# Flutter BottomNavigationBar in all pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want to make this: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf. I'm working with Getx. First I have a screen called NavigatorPage, the controller is NavigatorController(). The problem is that in my HomePage() I use Get.toNamed('otheRoute') and I lose the Appbar and the BottomNavigationBar. I nedd to achieve the result as the link.

This is my navigator page

```
    class NavigatorPage extends GetWidget<NavigatorController> {
  NavigatorPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      body: Obx(() => IndexedStack(
            index: controller.tabIndex.value,
            children: [
              HomePage(),
              //SecondPage(),
            ],
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(() => BottomNavigationBar(
              onTap: controller.changePage,
              currentIndex: controller.tabIndex.value,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'home',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.download),
                  label: 'download',
                ),
              ])),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my navigator controller

```
    class NavigatorController extends GetxController {
  var tabIndex = 0.obs;

  changePage(int index) {
    tabIndex(index);
    print('Index: $tabIndex');
  }
}
```

Comment: remove scaffold from all other pages

Comment: Your solution is not working :(

Comment: can you share more code

Comment: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf. I need this, the problem is when I user the Get.toNamed(). when I use that, flutter send to other page than not have appbar and bottomnavigationbar

Comment: can you tell why is the SecondPage() commented

Comment: due to an bindingerror, that comment do not affect